# ImageView's Drawabale tint is not working in Widget

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-widget, android-styles

I am creating a widget, but when I add `app:tint="@color/white"` it's showing tint in the **Design** Preview but when the widget loads the tint is not applied, the icon is still black, i need to add white tint to the imageview.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_explore_01"
    app:tint="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `ic_explore_01` xml file and edit the `fillColor` like the below code snippet.

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/white"
        android:pathData="M3,13h8L11,3L3,3v10zM3,21h8v-6L3,15v6zM13,21h8L21,11h-8v10zM13,3v6h8L21,3h-8z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: It worked, I was using a png image file, I changed it into a vector image and changed the fillColor to white, that did the job

Comment: !! Be aware that this is just a workaround; if you need to reuse the same image with different colors, this would not help, you have to duplicate the image for each color.

Comment: This workaround does not work for me (unknown color within the vector). Any better solutions? I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75254930/android-widget-imageview-vector-set-tint-programmatically-remoteviewscompat