# Android Widget ImageView (vector). Set tint (programmatically) RemoteViewsCompat

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I'm currently developing an Android widget containing an ImageView which is a Vector.
Now I need to set the tint of this ImageView (In best cast programmatically).
As a workaround (if this is not working), I could set the color within the ImageView, but not NOT within the image asset itself as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827469/imageviews-drawabale-tint-is-not-working-in-widget).
`app:tint="@color/colorPrimary"` within the ImageView seems to be ignored.
The following seems to work:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_plus_symbol"
    android:layout_width="16sp"
    android:layout_height="16sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_filled"
    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:ignore="UseAppTint" />
```

But is obviously not the best solution (`tools:ignore="UseAppTint"`).
Afterward, I could multiply the ImageView and set the color using the visibility of the different ImageViews.

But as said before, I actually want to set the color programmatically.